# Django set the language

Tags: django, internationalization

Im setting the language like this in my view.

```
    if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en':
        translation.activate('en')
    else:
        translation.activate('pt')
```

When going to the url /pt/foo/faa/

it works.

But the language is not set. Once I click on a link, like the about link, the url changes to /en/about/../ not /pt/about../ as I would think it should.

This is my urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    (r'^news/', include('news.urls')),
    ....
```

Settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ()
```

Am I understanding this the wrong way?

Comment: Can you show your `settings.py`, specifically the MIDDLEWARE and TEMPLATE CONTEXT PROCESSORS?

Comment: TEMPLATE CONTEXT PROCESSORS is not set to anything, its empty.

Answer (score 2):

As read in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/)

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n,
    )
```

You should have that in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

Now try to move up the `Locale` middleware like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

The order of middleware counts and locale should come after session.

It would be really hard to guess what will the problem be because there are many details in the process but it is quite well explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference). That's the algorithm django uses to detect i18n. Read it carefully following it's links. It must be something we're missing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Once I add that, it gives me this: Put 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting in order to use the admin application.. Then I add that like it said, all my media is broken. And also, it makes no difference, the language is not set.

Comment: Lol, I don't know what it have to do with `media`, let's read the doc further. Also, have you checked the you have USE_I18N=True?

Comment: Yup, thats also set to true. Seems like this is gonna be something stupid

Comment: Added a little tweak to middlewares in my answer

Comment: :( I've added the section of the docs which I think will solve the problem or at least explains how to do it right. I hope it can help more than my answer :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have some configuration issues in both your settings and your urls.

First, update your `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 )
 USE_I18N = True
```

Next, in your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    (r'^foo/fla/$', 'foo.flah.view'))

urlpatterns += patterns('/i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))
```

Note that you don't include the helper view in `i18n_patterns`.

Create a template with this form, which will set the language for the session:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
<select name="language">
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
<option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
    {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Or, if you want to set it "manually" in your view make sure you are returning a `RequestContext`, otherwise your language won't stick. Use the [`render()` shortcut](http://django.me/render) to make sure your views return the correct context.

Comment: I cannot get this working. Iv followed your code but using manual setting if language like this def index(request):
 if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en':
  translation.activate('en')
 else:
  translation.activate('pt')
 try:
  flatpage = FlatPage.objects.get(url='/')
 except:
  flatpage = []
 t = loader.get_template('base.html')
 c = RequestContext(request, {"flatpage":flatpage})
 return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

Comment: Its not working because you are using `HttpResponse`, use `render`